# How to add multiple hostnames using az cli

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I want to add multiple hostnames using az cli into app service, I am trying below command but it's only adding single hostname, is there any way to add multiple hostnames using single command, or is there any other command through which we can add multiple hostnames.

Command:

```
az webapp config hostname add --webapp-name  test --resource-group test123 --hostname testing.apetest.xyz --hostname testdns.apetest.xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Azure CLI cmdlet `az webapp config hostname add` you can add only one host name to the web app in single execution.

Alternatively, You can use `Set-AzWebApp` PowerShell cmdlet, which has a string array  parameter `[-HostNames <String[]>]` where you can pass & add multiple Hostnames to the web app.

```
Set-AzWebApp
   [-HostNames <String[]>]
   [-ResourceGroupName] <String>
   [-Name] <String>]
```

You can refer the below  documentations for more information:

- About the [**Set-AzWebApp**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/set-azwebapp?view=azps-7.1.0) cmdlet & list of  allowed Parameters.
- How to use [**Array of strings in PowerShell**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/set-azwebapp?view=azps-7.1.0).

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: Set-AzWebApp is replacing/overwriting the existing hostnames. few custom domains were already there in app service, when I executed the Set-AzWebApp command, it actually replaced the existing hostnames (there were 2) with the newly added hostname

Comment: Before running `Set-AzWebApp` cmdlet, would suggest you to pull the current list of host names & assign them to a variable then create a string array with the list of new host names you want to add & try appending the new hostname with previous hostname variable as show below script.

Comment: $webapp=Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName '<RGName>' -Name '<WebAppName>'| select -Property HostNames
[String[]] $hostname="yyy.org","xxx.in" ## list of hostname you want to add
if( $webapp -ne $null){
foreach( $item in $var){

    $webapp.HostNames += "$item"
}
 Set-AzWebApp -Name azwebapptestvedod -ResourceGroupName '<RGName>' -HostNames $webapp
}